# How do I stop playing music with simple audio?

Tags: python

How do you stop playing audio with simpleaudio?

```
def audio_1():
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("path/to/file.wav")
    play_obj = wave_obj.play()
```

I have a function here that plays the audio and is connected to a Tkinter button. Right now I need a function to stop playing any audio.

Comment: Can't you do `wave_obj.stop()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would either use *wave_obj.stop()* to stop that specific audio, or you can use *sa.stopall()*, which will stop all audio. The code should either look like this:

```
def audio_1():
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("path/to/file.wav")
    play_obj = wave_obj.play()

    # Play for as long as you want
    stop_obj = wave_obj.stop()
```

Or this:

```
def audio_1():
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("path/to/file.wav")
    play_obj = wave_obj.play()

    # Play for as long as you want
    sa.stopall()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call `.stop()` on the play object:

```python
def audio_1():
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("path/to/file.wav")
    play_obj = wave_obj.play()
    play_obj.stop()
```

Answer (score -1):

See *[simpleaudio](https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpleaudio.html)*.

As suggested in [the earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64581899/how-do-i-stop-playing-music-with-simple-audio/73272800#comment114193249_64581899), you can do it using *wave_obj.stop* or *sa.stopall()* which will *stop* all currently playing audio.